# Set product status with magmi (product enabled/disbaled)

Tags: php, magento, csv, import, magmi

I used Value Replacer and Clumn Mapper to set product status (enabled/disabled) but i have no effect in my magento!

Here my settings. Somebody have the same problems?

```
CSV content is:
nr;rack;
10001-52;Yes;
10001-55;No;
```

To use magmi, first i need convert the data to this correct content:

```
sku;status;
10001-52;1;
10001-55;2;
```

I use this plugins settings to convert the data:
**Column mapper**
Mapped columns list:nr,rack
nr = sku
rack = status

**Value Replacer**
Replaced attributes: Yes,No
Yes=1
No=2
(For magento "product status" disabled or enabled)

**Magmi settings**

```
CSV separator is: ;
CSV Enclosure: i leave it blank
Multiselect value separator: ;
```

Thank you so much!
Tommy